# Animate layout changes using a transition in same layout

Tags: android, animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to create my first compound control it should look like this:

[image: target goal]

I was thinking in using a LinearLayout for the container and one TextView for each number, the selected number would have the rounded background and when the user clicks on the number remove the background from the current one and set it to the new one, and then somehow get android to animate that.

This looks something like a shared element transition only that this is not an element, just the background.

**How can I accomplish this transition?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have created this:

```
Relativelayout - (White background, rounded corners)
      └ Framelayout - (Green background, rounded corners)
      └ LinearLayout
             └ TextView 1 |  TextView 2 | TextView 3
```

Then get the position, center, of a textview upon selection and use that position to move the `Framelayout`. Use an `interpolator`,[`AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.html), for the animation. You can animate with an XML or with code, it's up to you.

You can use `ImageView` or others instead of `FrameLayout`, this is an opinion based decision.